# How do I mock a future's onComplete method?

Tags: scala, akka, mockito, specs2

I have an Akka actor that works with a message containing a future. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
case class MyMessage(s: Future[String])

class MyWorker extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MyMessage(future) =>
      future onComplete {
        case Success(s) => sender ! s
        case Failure(e) => throw e
      }
  }
}
```

I am using TestActorRef to test it in specs2, but when I write a spec like this:

```
class MyWorkerSpec extends Specification with Mockito {

  val worker = TestActorRef(new MyWorker)

  "MyMessage" should {

    "return the string from a successful result" in {
      val message = MyMessage(Future("test"))
      val result = worker ? message
      result.value.get must_== Success("test")
    }

  }
}
```

...then it fails with `NoSuchElementException: None.get`, and the Akka system complains about dead letters.

Figuring that this is probably because it isn't waiting for the future to complete, I decided to try mocking the future and stubbing the `onSuccess` method. I'm not sure how to do this, though, because the `func` argument is evidently an `Any`.

```
class MyWorkerSpec extends Specification with Mockito {

  val worker = TestActorRef(new MyWorker)

  "MyMessage" should {

    "return the string from a successful result" in {
      val mockFuture = mock[Future[String]]
      mockFuture.onComplete(any[Try[String] => String]) answers {
        func => {
          func(Success("test"))
        }
      }
      worker ! MyMessage(mockFuture)
    }
  }
}
```

How does one mock a future like this? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How are you initializing that `TestActorRef` under the hood? Is it actually going through `actorOf(...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any mocking required here.

1- How about creating your `Future` like this: `MyMessage(Future.successful("test"))`, that way it is completed when you create it.

2- You should wait for your actor to reply before calling `value` on `result`:

```
val result = worker ? message
Await.result(result, duration) must_== Success("test")
```

See: [http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await%24)

3- Sending an instance of `Future` to an actor sounds like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: Big +1 on point 3. A `Future` can't be sent between VMs, so sending them between actors destroys the scalability of the application.

Comment: I'm new to scala and functional programming in general, so I'm all ears about why you think sending a future to an actor is a bad idea. The future is being created by an earlier actor, and I thought it would be good to defer waiting for the result until the latest possible moment. The problem of course is that it adds this complexity.

Comment: Just saw wingedsubmariner's comment -- very good point. I'll stop sending futures.

Comment: You should read more about the `Future`/`Promise` API. Calling `onComplete` from an actor buys you exactly nothing in comparison to just calling `onComplete` after creating the `Future`. `onComplete` is non-blocking, you are just registering a handler to be executed when the `Future` completes. A great resource to learn more: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html

Comment: I see what you mean about `onComplete`. I had mistaken it for a blocking API before.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but the original problem of getting dead letters when using `onComplete` in the actor remains. I've created a new question to get at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049457/akka-dead-letter-when-using-implicitsender-and-future